# Email always going to spam folder using code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to send mail to a customer when their registration was completed. I used the built in email function of codeigniter. The mail sends successfully but not in the index, spam folder only. I have used below code to send mail:

```
$target_file = APPPATH.'views/email/test.tpl';
$assets_url =   base_url().'/assets/images/';
$body = file_get_contents($target_file);
$email_variable = array('(uname)'=>$email, '(sitename)'=>$sitename,'(link)'=>$link,'(pwd)'=>"",'(assests_url)' => $assets_url,'(base_url)' => base_url());
$body = strtr($body,$email_variable);
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->from($from, $sitename);
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject($sub);
$this->email->message($body);
$this->email->send();
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How should we know _why_ your messages are considered SPAM? We are good, true. But we are not _that_ good that we can somehow magically _guess_ what your messages content might be and what rules the receiving side applies to your messages.

Comment: There are many chances why your emails are going to spam,you should check this http://www.activecampaign.com/help/improving-delivery/

Comment: Nothing to do with code. Most of time its from your host provider. Check with host support.

Comment: This happens due to the server most of the time. May be your host provider is black listed.